# Connected component Labeling of specific Size objects

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv, connected-components

Suppose one image has different objects of different sizes(50pixel,100pixels and 200pixel) in it. How can i Label only those objects which have 100pixels OR Greater than 100pixels & less than 200pixels.

I have labeled all objects in image by using AForge's Connected Components Labeling Method. But I don't know how to do same for specific size objects.

```
ConnectedComponentsLabeling Labeling = new ConnectedComponentsLabeling();

Bitmap labeledImage = Labeling.Apply(BinaryImage);

int Objects =Labeling.ObjectCount;
```

Solution

```
 "// Applying Blob Filter
        BlobsFiltering filter = new BlobsFiltering();
        filter.CoupledSizeFiltering = true;
        filter.MinHeight = 4;
        filter.MinWidth = 4;
        Bitmap FilterImage = filter.Apply(BinaryImage);

        // Counting Ojects
        ConnectedComponentsLabeling Labeling = new ConnectedComponentsLabeling();
        Bitmap labeledImage = Labeling.Apply(FilterImage);
         int TotalNumberofTeeth = Labeling.ObjectCount;
```

Comment: Do you have any sample code?  What have you tried?

Comment: @CarlProthman Yes i have done labeling for all objects using Aforge .  I have added its code in question.

Comment: Just did it using Aforge's BlobsFiltering Method. :)

Comment: Cool, post your solution?

Comment: @CarlProthman sory for late reply. I have added solution in question. Above. :)